# Is it possible to have a smaller dataset than when using factors?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to decrease the memory footprint of some of my datasets where I have a small set of factors per columns (repeated a large number of times). Are there better ways to minimize it? For comparison, this is what I get from just using factors:

```r
library(pryr)

N <- 10 * 8
M <- 10
```

Initial data:

```r
test <- data.frame(A = c(rep(strrep("A", M), N), rep(strrep("B", N), N)))
object_size(test)
# 1.95 kB
```

Using Factors:

```r
test2 <- as.factor(test$A)
object_size(test2)
# 1.33 kB
```

Aside: I naively assumed that they replaced the strings with a number and was pleasantly surprised to see `test2` smaller than `test3`. Can anyone point me to some material on how to optimize factor representation?

```r
test3 <- data.frame(A = c(rep("1", N), rep("2", N)))
object_size(test3)
# 1.82 kB
```

Comment: FYI: This questin is technically off-topic (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic bullet 4) because it is just asking for a recommendation for additional reading material. Do you have a specific use case that you are needing help with or is this purely informational?

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid the difference is minimal.

The principle would be easy enough: instead of (in your example) 160 strings, you would just be storing 2, along with 160 integers (which are only 4 bytes).
Except that R kind of stores character internally the same way.

Every modern language supports string of (virtually) unlimited length. Which gives the problem that you can't store a vector (or array) of strings as one contiguous block, as any element can be reset to arbitrary length. So if another value is assigned to one element, which happened to be somewhat longer, that would mean the rest of the array would have to be shifted. Or the OS/language should reserve large amounts of space for each string.
Therefore, strings are stored at whatever place in memory is convenient, and arrays (or vectors in R) are stored as blocks of *pointers* to the place where the value actually is.
In the early days of R, each pointer pointed to another place in memory, even if the actual value was the same. So in your example, 160 pointers to 160 memory locations. But that's changed, nowadays it's implemented as 160 pointers to 2 memory locations.
There may be some small differences, mainly because a factor can normally support only 2^31-1 levels, meaning 32-bits integers are enough to store it, while a character mostly uses 64-bits pointers. Then again, there's more overhead in factors.
Generally, there *may* be some advantage in using factor if you really have a large percentage duplicates, but if that's not the case it may even harm your memory usage.

And the example you provided doesn't work, as you're comparing a data.frame with a factor, instead of the bare character.
Even stronger: when I reproduce your example, I only get your results if I set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE`, so you're comparing a factor to a factor in a data.frame.
Comparing the results otherwise gives a lot smaller difference: 1568 for character, 1328 for a factor.
And that only works if you have a lot of the same values, if you look at this you see that the factor can be larger:

```
> object.size(factor(sample(letters)))
2224 bytes
> object.size(sample(letters))
1712 bytes
```

So generally, there is no real way to compress your data while still keeping it easy to work with, except for using common sense in what you actually want to store.

Comment: That's a good explanation of how R works internally.  I believe the maximum number of factors is `2^31-1`, unless R allows negative/zero factor indexing.

Comment: I don't know if the underlying representation is signed or unsigned integer, but anyway I just wrote it as "it needs 32 bits, and has way more possible levels then you'd possibly ever need". But it could well be that it's indeed `2^31-1`

Comment: A factor is just an INTSXP with attributes, and INTSXP is just a `signed int` array.  You can verify this with `attributes(my_factor) <- NULL`.

Comment: Also in the `factor` function, R uses `levels <- levels[is.na(match(levels, exclude))]` which wouldn't work if R used unsigned integers for factors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a direct answer for your question but here is a few information from the book ["Advanced R"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) by Hadley Wickham:

> ### Factors
>
> One important use of attributes is to define factors. A factor
>   is a vector that can contain only predefined values, and is used to
>   store categorical data. Factors are built on top of integer vectors
>   using two attributes: the class, “factor”, which makes them behave
>   differently from regular integer vectors, and the levels, which
>   defines the set of allowed values.

Also:

> "While factors look (and often behave) like character vectors, they
>   are actually integers. Be careful when treating them like strings.
>   Some string methods (like gsub() and grepl()) will coerce factors to
>   strings, while others (like nchar()) will throw an error, and still
>   others (like c()) will use the underlying integer values. For this
>   reason, it’s usually best to explicitly convert factors to character
>   vectors if you need string-like behaviour. In early versions of R,
>   there was a memory advantage to using factors instead of character
>   vectors, but this is no longer the case."

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in R called `fst` ([Lightning Fast Serialization of Data Frames for R)](http://www.fstpackage.org/)
 , in which you can create compressed `fst` objects for your data frame. A detailed explanation can be found in the [fst-package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fst/fst.pdf), but I'll briefly explain about how to use it and how much space an `fst` object takes. First, Let's make your `test` dataframe a bit larger, as follows:

```
library(pryr)
N <- 1000 * 8
M <- 100
test <- data.frame(A = c(rep(strrep("A", M), N), rep(strrep("B", N), N)))
object_size(test)
# 73.3 kB
```

Now, let's convert this dataframe into an `fst` object, as follows:

```
install.packages("fst") #install the package
library(fst) #load the package
path <- paste0(tempfile(), ".fst") #create a temporary '.fst' file
write_fst(test, path) #write the dataframe into the '.fst' file
test2 <- fst(path) #load the data as an fst object
object_size(test2)
# 2.14 kB
```

The disk space for the created `.fst` file is `434 bytes`. You can deal with `test2` as a normal dataframe (as far as I tried).

Hope this helps.